# Check if at least one checkbox is checked to enable a link

Tags: html, jquery, forms

I have a form with multi step, and i have a problem on one step, i want to block users to be able to progress in the form if they didn't check at least one checkbox

The problem is, if i check anything, the CTA is clickable, but if i uncheck my checkbox, i still can click on the CTA and progress in the form

```js
$('input[name="PROBLEM"]').on('change',function(){
                 $(".four").removeClass('isDisabled', this.checked);
             });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="answer">
   <div id="row1">
       <span class="answer">
           <input name="PROBLEM" type="checkbox" id="crash" value="crash">
           <label for="crash">Crash/bugs</label>
       </span>
      <span class="answer">
          <input name="PROBLEM" type="checkbox" id="transfer" value="transfer">
          <label for="transfer">Transfer</label>
       </span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="cta spacebtn">
    <a href="#partfour" class="isDisabled four"></a>
</div>
```

I tried with length > 0 but somehow didn't succeed (probably because i'm still a beginner with JS)

Any idea on how i can fix that ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: try `$(".four").toggleClass('isDisabled', $('input[name="PROBLEM"]:checked').length == 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell [toggleClass](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp#:%7E:text=The%20toggleClass()%20method%20toggles,This%20creates%20a%20toggle%20effect.) to only add `isDisabled` class if length of checked checkbox is 0.

> $(selector).toggleClass(classname,function(index,currentclass),switch)

> **switch**          Optional. A Boolean value specifying if the class should only be added (true), or only be removed (false)

```js
$('input[name="PROBLEM"]').on('change',function(){
   const checkedBox = $("input[name='PROBLEM']:checked").length
   $(".four").toggleClass('isDisabled', checkedBox === 0);
});
```

```css
.isDisabled {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="answer">
   <div id="row1">
       <span class="answer">
           <input name="PROBLEM" type="checkbox" id="crash" value="crash">
           <label for="crash">Crash/bugs</label>
       </span>
      <span class="answer">
          <input name="PROBLEM" type="checkbox" id="transfer" value="transfer">
          <label for="transfer">Transfer</label>
       </span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="cta spacebtn">
    <a href="#partfour" class="isDisabled four">CTA</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please consider leaving a note with your answer explaining the OP why this solves the problem

Comment: Thank you ! It's working ! I was not using the length method correctly